# How can I generate data using nested loop in mysql/mariadb ? I have tried several times to generate each day 100 entry but it generate only once

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, while-loop, mariadb

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_data2()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE i < 10 DO
    WHILE j <100 DO
        INSERT INTO notifications (id,customer_id,tos,device_type,message,types,read_status,created_at,updated_at) 
        VALUES (
        null,10000,'tos','device_type','message ','Types',1, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL i DAY),"%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s"),
        DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 2 DAY),"%Y-%m-%d"));
        SET j = j + 1; 
    END WHILE;
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This code not working as I expected. I want to generate each day 100 data using while loop. But each time it is looping one times only for 1 day. If you execute my code you can understand that issue. Need expert solution in better way.
Example:
For 2022-Jan-01 100 entry
For 2022-Dec-31 100 entry
For 2022-Dec-30 100 entry

Comment: Side note: Since you do all that formatting, which would otherwise isn't needed, it seems like `created_at` and `updated_at` are of a string data type? If yes, you should fix this and use an appropriate date/time data type instead.

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statement for `notifications`, so we can test this.

Comment: You need to initialise j after every I loop

Comment: till 100 it it work then end here i is not looping.

Comment: I suspect I is looping but you don’t see it, I suggest you put a select into code immediately before j loop

Comment: I checked through i=8  as  initial value and  j=0 as initial value then output like (8,0),(8,1)....(8,99)  that means i =8 every times till j=99 then loop end. This is the issue here.

Comment: @P.Salmon Make that an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should reset j inside every I iteration

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_data2()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE i < 10 DO
     SET J = 0;
     #SELECT I,J;
    WHILE j <100 DO
        INSERT INTO notifications (id,customer_id,tos,device_type,message,types,read_status,created_at,updated_at) 
        VALUES (
        null,10000,'tos','device_type','message ','Types',1, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL i DAY),"%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s"),
        DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 2 DAY),"%Y-%m-%d"));
        SET j = j + 1; 
    END WHILE;
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85c31b4c54428d570057a31af38d1a03

Comment: Yes , it is working. This is what I am expecting. I did little mistake here. Did not initialized inside while loop. Thanks @P.Salmon for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that you tag MariaDB. Then you can directly use the sequel Engine to do that with a Query like this.

INSERT INTO notifications (id,customer_id,tos,device_type,message,types,read_status,created_at,updated_at)

```
SELECT
     NULL
     ,10000
     ,'tos','device_type','message '
     ,'Types'
     ,1
     , NOW() - INTERVAL dayLoop.seq   DAY 
     , NOW() - INTERVAL dayLoop.seq+1 DAY 

FROM ( SELECT seq FROM seq_1_to_10 ) AS perDayLoop
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT seq FROM seq_1_to_10 ) AS dayLoop
ORDER BY dayLoop.seq, perDayLoop.seq
```

**samples**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT seq, NOW() - INTERVAL seq DAY FROM seq_1_to_5;
+-----+--------------------------+
| seq | NOW() - INTERVAL seq DAY |
+-----+--------------------------+
|   1 | 2022-01-07 09:48:09      |
|   2 | 2022-01-06 09:48:09      |
|   3 | 2022-01-05 09:48:09      |
|   4 | 2022-01-04 09:48:09      |
|   5 | 2022-01-03 09:48:09      |
+-----+--------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

**sample2**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT
    ->  NULL
    ->  ,10000
    ->  ,'tos','device_type','message '
    ->  ,'Types'
    ->  ,1
    ->  , NOW() - INTERVAL dayLoop.seq   DAY 
    ->  , NOW() - INTERVAL dayLoop.seq+1 DAY 
    -> , perDayLoop.seq 
    -> , dayLoop.seq
    -> 
    -> FROM ( SELECT seq FROM seq_1_to_10 ) AS perDayLoop
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT seq FROM seq_1_to_10 ) AS dayLoop
    -> ORDER BY dayLoop.seq, perDayLoop.seq;
+------+-------+-----+-------------+----------+-------+---+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-----+-----+
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | NOW() - INTERVAL dayLoop.seq   DAY | NOW() - INTERVAL dayLoop.seq+1 DAY | seq | seq |
+------+-------+-----+-------------+----------+-------+---+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-----+-----+
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-07 09:49:25                | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                |   1 |   1 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-07 09:49:25                | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                |   2 |   1 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-07 09:49:25                | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                |   3 |   1 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-07 09:49:25                | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                |   4 |   1 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-07 09:49:25                | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                |   5 |   1 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-07 09:49:25                | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                |   6 |   1 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-07 09:49:25                | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                |   7 |   1 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-07 09:49:25                | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                |   8 |   1 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-07 09:49:25                | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                |   9 |   1 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-07 09:49:25                | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                |  10 |   1 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                |   1 |   2 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                |   2 |   2 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                |   3 |   2 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                |   4 |   2 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                |   5 |   2 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                |   6 |   2 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                |   7 |   2 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                |   8 |   2 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                |   9 |   2 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-06 09:49:25                | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                |  10 |   2 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                |   1 |   3 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                |   2 |   3 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                |   3 |   3 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                |   4 |   3 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                |   5 |   3 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                |   6 |   3 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                |   7 |   3 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                |   8 |   3 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                |   9 |   3 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-05 09:49:25                | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                |  10 |   3 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                |   1 |   4 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                |   2 |   4 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                |   3 |   4 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                |   4 |   4 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                |   5 |   4 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                |   6 |   4 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                |   7 |   4 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                |   8 |   4 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                |   9 |   4 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-04 09:49:25                | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                |  10 |   4 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                |   1 |   5 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                |   2 |   5 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                |   3 |   5 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                |   4 |   5 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                |   5 |   5 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                |   6 |   5 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                |   7 |   5 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                |   8 |   5 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                |   9 |   5 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:49:25                | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                |  10 |   5 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                |   1 |   6 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                |   2 |   6 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                |   3 |   6 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                |   4 |   6 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                |   5 |   6 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                |   6 |   6 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                |   7 |   6 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                |   8 |   6 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                |   9 |   6 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-02 09:49:25                | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                |  10 |   6 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                |   1 |   7 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                |   2 |   7 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                |   3 |   7 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                |   4 |   7 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                |   5 |   7 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                |   6 |   7 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                |   7 |   7 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                |   8 |   7 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                |   9 |   7 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2022-01-01 09:49:25                | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                |  10 |   7 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                |   1 |   8 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                |   2 |   8 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                |   3 |   8 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                |   4 |   8 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                |   5 |   8 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                |   6 |   8 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                |   7 |   8 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                |   8 |   8 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                |   9 |   8 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-31 09:49:25                | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                |  10 |   8 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                |   1 |   9 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                |   2 |   9 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                |   3 |   9 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                |   4 |   9 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                |   5 |   9 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                |   6 |   9 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                |   7 |   9 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                |   8 |   9 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                |   9 |   9 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-30 09:49:25                | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                |  10 |   9 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                | 2021-12-28 09:49:25                |   1 |  10 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                | 2021-12-28 09:49:25                |   2 |  10 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                | 2021-12-28 09:49:25                |   3 |  10 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                | 2021-12-28 09:49:25                |   4 |  10 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                | 2021-12-28 09:49:25                |   5 |  10 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                | 2021-12-28 09:49:25                |   6 |  10 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                | 2021-12-28 09:49:25                |   7 |  10 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                | 2021-12-28 09:49:25                |   8 |  10 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                | 2021-12-28 09:49:25                |   9 |  10 |
| NULL | 10000 | tos | device_type | message  | Types | 1 | 2021-12-29 09:49:25                | 2021-12-28 09:49:25                |  10 |  10 |
+------+-------+-----+-------------+----------+-------+---+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-----+-----+
100 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: It looks little advance topics, but answer is same what I am expected. I learnt new things from you. You explained it very well . Thanks @Bernd Buffen for your comments.